# Form API Ajax trigger callback with size of input

Tags: 8, forms, javascript, ajax

I use the API Form of Drupal 8 to create my form.
I had an ajax callback on a field:

```
$form['association']['numero'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('foo'),
        '#size' => 10,
        '#maxlength' => 10,
        '#suffix' => '<div id="ajax_error"></div>',
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::fetchApiData',
            'event' => 'change',
            'prevent' => 'click',
        ],
    );
```

with my callback function :

```
public function fetchApiData(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    return 'foo';
}
```

It's all working fine, but i want to trigger the callback when the user **writes 10 characters precisely**. Does anyone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

1) Decide on an event name. In this code, the event name will be 'overminlength'

2) In the form element being defined using the Form API, set your #ajax as normal, but set the #ajax 'event' to the event name chosen in step 1:

```
'#ajax' => [
  'wrapper' => 'some_wrapper',
  'callback' => 'some_callback',
  // Set the custom event here:
  'event' => 'overminlength',
],
```

3) Create a custom JS file and attach it to the field

```
'#attached' => [
  'library' => ['mymdodule/mylibrary'],
],
```

4) Add a [$.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) listener to the field.

- In the callback, count the number of characters in the field
- If it's more than X characters, call [$.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), and trigger the event from step 1

  ```
  (function($, Drupal) {

    "use strict";

    function fieldwatcher(context) {
      $(context).find("#edit-myfield").once("fieldwatcher").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function() {
          // Change '3' to the number of characters after which you want to
          // trigger the ajax.
          if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
            $(this).trigger("overminlength");
          }
        });
      });
    }

    Drupal.behaviors.testScript = {
      attach: function(context) {
        fieldwatcher(context);
      }
    };

  }(jQuery, Drupal));
  ```

Comment: Hello Jaypan and thank you for your response.
I don't really understand your point, can you please explain me more ?
Regards,

Comment: Well, my answer is all jQuery and JavaScript based. If you don't understand how to work with those, the answer I gave above isn't going to help you, and I can't really teach JS and jQuery on Drupal answers. If you are looking for a method of doing what you want purely through the Form API, the answer is that it cannot be done. The solution I gave above would be a custom one that requires custom JS coding.

Comment: Ho okay, yes i can do that with javascript but my question was more about using the Form API, but it seems we actually can't.

Comment: That's correct. The Form API is great, but this is not functionality it provides by default. It may make for an interesting add-on however.

Comment: I've actually tested my theory, and it works. I've re-written my post above to show specific instructions.

Comment: Hello, thank for your theory and code, it works well !